# Microphone not working?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype

I am new to ubuntu and have recently installed the latest version instead of windows.
I installed skype and the microphne seemed to not be working...
So I checked settings and the built in mic on my laptop wasn't picking up any sound.
I have installed the plugins for the pulseaudio server and it's still not working.

I would be grateful for help.
Thanks

***UPDATE***

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269 Analog [ALC269 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

This is what came up in my terminal after the code...

Comment: Type `arecord -l` in a terminal and post the output

Comment: Have you read [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1386638)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed pavucontrol and opened it via the terminal.In the input levels from the internal microphone I made one channel maxed and the other placed down to zero. And my mic works now in skype.

Comment: was able to set my webcam mic as fallback and now it works with skype on 14.10, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in Ubuntu or Linux, you must be patient and do more search for solving your problems. First of all check the following address and follow the links there, you may find your answer.
 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AudioCapture

It's a matter of time that you will get to use the question and answer sites and how to use a free and open source operating system. You will find more exciting aspects of using Ubuntu. For a while, it is better to use both Ubuntu and windows together. You can install them on one system. After enough experiencing Ubuntu and become comfortable with it, you will install only Ubuntu.

Comment: Also my mic seems to work in audacity just not in settings it's not showing when i speak. Skype not working too..